# Find an equation of a plane π that passes through point P = (0, 1, 0) and is parallel to vectors ~a = [−1, 3, 0], ~b = [3, 1, −5]

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

I need some help with the second one, can someone help me to solve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYIxy.png)

Comment: How did you solve the first one?

Comment: @JohnDouma https://ibb.co/PDjTJGC

Comment: This is the same. A plane parallel to $a$ and $b$ will have its normal vector parallel to the cross product of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write $$\vec{x}=\vec{OP}+s\vec{a}+t\vec{b}$$ where $s,t$ are real numbers.
It is $$\vec{x}=[0,1,0]+s[-1,3,0]+t[3,1,-5]$$
and from here we get the system
$$x=-s+3t$$
$$y=1+3s+t$$
$$z=-5t$$
It is better for you now? With the equation $$t=-\frac{z}{5}$$ you can eliminate $t$ then with $$s=-x-\frac{3}{5}z$$ you can eliminate $s$

Comment: I can't really understand your equation, can you show me on my example?

Comment: So, the answer is 3 equations, am i right?

Comment: You can also eliminate the parameters to obtain an equation of the form $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with the number $3$?

Comment: I get $$3x+y+2z-1=0$$ as an equation of your plane.